# Interacting with ListView (NamingContainer) Item Controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls, code-behind, traversal

If only there were an easier way of traversing ASP.NET controls in the codebehind. This has been the bane of my existence as an interning .NET developer. I would like some help identifying the proper member of the `ListView` controls. I've deleted all the presentation code in the markup to make it easier to look, since it isn't relevant anyway. Here's the situation:

**Markup**

```html
<asp:ListView ID="NewProduct" runat="server" DataSourceID="NewProductSDS" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="NewProductTable" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="editProductName" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                </asp:TableCell>
                <!-- I want this value to be transferred to my edit combobox -->
                <asp:TableCell ID="NewProductName" runat="server">
                    <%# Eval("Product").ToString.Trim()%>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="NewProductTable" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="updateProductName" runat="server"  CommandName="Rename" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cancelProductName" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    <!-- Autocomplete Combobox, NOTE: The DDL is not displayed -->
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="NewProductName_ddl" runat="server" DataSourceID="productLineSDS" DataTextField="Product" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NewProductName_cb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <button id="NewProductName_btn" type="button"></button>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

**Codebehind (VB)**

```vb
Protected Sub ItemClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles NewProduct.ItemCommand
    Dim lv As ListView = DirectCast(sender, ListView)
    Dim i As Integer = e.Item.DisplayIndex
    'Session State Attempt
    Session.Add("NewProductKey", lv.DataKeys(i).Value)
    'URL State Attempt
    NewProductKey = lv.DataKeys(i).Value

    If e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
        Session.Add("NewProductKey", lv.DataKeys(i).Value)
        Try
            'This DDL is in the <EditItemTemplate> section.
            '  Need to set "selected" to value from "NewProductName" table cell
            '  For some reason I can't "FindControl" on this one.
            Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(lv.Items(0).FindControl("NewProductName_ddl"), DropDownList)
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(lv.Items(0).FindControl("NewProductName_cb"), TextBox)
            tb.Text = "test" 'BROKEN, can't even set the text. How can I ensure this control exists at this time?
            'This TableCell is in the <ItemTemplate> section. I can get this
            '  value back just fine.
            Dim pn As TableCell = DirectCast(lv.Items(0).FindControl("NewProductName"), TableCell)
            ddl.SelectedValue = CInt(Session.Item("NewProductKey"))
            ddl.Text = ddl.SelectedValue
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        'Wireup the Combobox using some custom Javascript.
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType], "", "cbsetup(""#NewProductName_cb"", ""#NewProductName_ddl"");", True)
    ElseIf e.CommandName = "Rename" Then
        Session.Add("NewProductKey", lv.DataKeys(i).Value)
        'Update the Product Name with the new value as entered in the TextBox control.
        Try
            Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(lv.Items(0).FindControl("NewProductName_ddl"), DropDownList)
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(lv.Items(0).FindControl("NewProductName_cb"), TextBox)
            Dim pKey As String = NewProductKey.ToString
            Dim pName As String = tb.Text 'Should take the value from the "NewProductName" TableCell
            Using connection As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
                'Query using pName and pKey works perfectly when run from SQL Server.
                '  The issue I'm having is capturing the values from the controls.
                Dim updateQuery As New SqlCommand(RenameProductQueryStr, connection)
                connection.Open()
                updateQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
                connection.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

What I want to accomplish is for my Combobox to have the value of the clicked row already selected in the DDL AND the text entered into the TextBox. I think the issue lies with my inability to `FindControl` on a control in the `<EditItemTemplate>` section from a Command initiated by a control in the `<ItemTemplate>` section. Here's what I want it to look like. The first image is item mode, the second is edit mode.

[image]  ------->  [image]

It's not shown in my codebehind block above, but I'm using the following inside my "Edit" command block to try to identify the structure and how to grab my Combobox controls to act on them, but to no avail :(

```
For Each item As Control In lv.Items
    debugLabel.Text += ", Items: " + item.ToString + "<br />"
Next
```

I don't know whether to use `lv.Items(0).FindControl("")`, `lv.Items(0).Parent.FindControl("")`, `lv.Parent.FindControl("")`, `lv.FindControl("")`, etc, or WHAT?!

> I mean **GIMME A FREAKING BREAK MICROSOFT**!!! Get your stuff together!! You're making developers' lives everywhere freaking MISERABLE!! Not only with IE, but with a very inconsistent .NET framework where every control has a different member structure as is implemented differently. FCOL!!! I've decided to make an extensive set of tutorials and guides for exploring the .NET framework and how certain controls translate to html, and so on, once I roll out my new website. This is a major shortcoming in the API imho. As a new developer, it is extremely difficult to tell what is going on behind the scenes. I aim to make that a bit more evident to those with more of an html and traditional programming background. I've learned one thing, I have a serious love/hate relationship with frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-framed my asking of this question months later in hopes of simplifying it and increasingly the likelihood of receiving adequate assistance. I have posted the answer to both of these questions, thanks to some guidance from the referenced question.

[**Go here to see my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994152/accessing-controls-on-listview-edit-command) :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think that's what `Bind` is for.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SomeValue") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SomeValue") %>' ... />
</EditItemTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

I think this is what you're after:

```
For Each item As ListViewItem In lv.Items 
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(item.FindControl("NewProductName_ddl"), DropDownList)
    If ddl IsNot Nothing Then
        'your code
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I added some images. It doesn't make sense to have the Combobox displayed in my `ItemTemplate`. Btw, I've read that it's generally not good practice to use inline program logic in your markup. Is that not true in this case since Views are such a pain?

Comment: It's discouraged to use inline code blocks if it can be avoided, but in the context of a databound control it is completely okay.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't really think this is the answer I'm looking for in this case. Or at least I cannot see the connection. At any rate, I want to keep my templates as they are, i.e. I do not wish my Combobox controls to be in the `ItemTemplate` section. No offense. Other ideas? or further explanation? We can chat again if you like. Let me know, and thanks again ;)

Comment: I'm not telling you to put them there. I thought that's what you were doing. So if nothing in the `ItemTemplate` is editable, why can't you get the correct value in the `EditItemTemplate`?

Comment: Sorry, haha, Perhaps I'm not being clear. Please refer to the images I posted. Notice the first one shows the elements of my `ItemTemplate` which contains some `LinkButton`s and another `TableCell` with the name of the Product. The second image shows the elements of my `EditItemTemplate` which contains a couple other buttons and my Combobox. Upon clicking the "Edit" button from the `ItemTemplate` I wish for the value of the `TableCell` to be used to seed the Combobox of the `EditItemTemplate`. Hopefully that explains it better. :)

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. The loop below the pictures is wrong, I believe. You need to loop through each `ListViewItem` in `lv.Items`, and find the controls in the `ListViewItem`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I was only using that loop for debugging. I should be able to access the control directly using `FindControl` right?... I'm in chat.

Comment: I still can't seem to find the control using your code. If you have any other suggestions or become available for chat I'll give them a try. But since I'm due for Beta on Monday, I simply must attend to more important issues for now and come back to this later. Until then...